# DNS policies Windows Domain Controller

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

We have established our network based on MS Windows Active directory and domain controller.Also we have similar web application hosted on two different servers. Our requirement is as follows-

1. Whenever a user on the network wants to access the web application, the DNS server should provide the IP address of the server based on weights assigned. However if the desired application server is down it should provided IP address of the other server
2. Can I somehow check the health of application server using DNS polices in Windows DC environment ?
3. Can the DNS records be updated based on the availability of application server ?

Comment: No. This is what a load balancer does, it has builtin health checks. DNS is a name to numerical IP address service.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as a base function of Active Directory DNS. You need a network load balancer. F5 BigIP DNS works in the way described and there are other load balancers that do the same. You can set preferences for load balancing, you can configure health check rules, and it will update the DNS records based on the results of those health checks.